# How to determine the number of hidden neurons from the structure of the data and their classes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification

In this link : http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-03-NN-Manifolds-Topology/

Under the heading 'Topology and Classification', it has been said that at least 3 neurons are required in the hidden layer to successfully separate the classes of this data:

[image]

I do not understand why the number of neurons has to be 3. The visualization shows that a 3D space can successfully linearly separate the classes, but I do not understand how that 3D space is generated.

So, I have two questions.

**1. How has the visualization been done using the hidden neurons and their weights(and why does it fail for 2 hidden neurons?)**

**2. Why does the number of neurons have to be 3, and how can that be determined by just looking at the 2D data from the dataset?**

Answer (score 3):

There is one important piece of information missing in your question, but given in the referenced blog: The neurons have a sigmoid activation function ($\tanh$), implying that each neuron produces a linear boundary.

Now, from the definition of class $B$ you can simply ignore the part $d(x, 0) < 1$. It's a red herring, not relevant to the class boundary. It is, however, important that the class $A$ is $< 1/3$ from the center, and class $B$ $> 2/3$ from the center. The simplest class boundary, in terms of straight lines, is a equilateral triangle with a height of one:

[image: Classes in an equilateral triangle]

You need a neuron for each line, $a$, $b$, and $c$, and each of them outputs $>0$ if the input is on the "in-side" (in the direction of the origin, looking from the line). In the next layer (output) you simply sum the results of the previous layer and threshold it, so that the output is positive only if all three produced a positive result. This is basically a logical "AND" on the three neurons.

So, to answer you **first question**: Each axis shows the (distance $\cdot$ direction) from the corresponding line (actually, in the 3D-visualisation one axis (left) goes in the opposite direction, but that doesn't matter, as you can simply multiply the weight leading from that neuron by -1. Just imagine the opposite sign on this axis, it simplifies the explanation). You can see that all points from class $A$ (red) are in the top-left edge, having positive distance $\le 1$, on each axis. For class $B$, i) the signed distances can be larger and than $1$ and ii) one of them always has a different sign than the other two.

Your **second question**: The number of neurons can be greater than 3, but not smaller. You need at least three neurons to fully enclose the class $A$, because triangle is the simplest closed shape in 2D.

Comment: Okay. I understood that there must be three neurons, but I still have some clarifications.

1. As you've given a rough estimate of the lines, is the job of the **tanh** non-linearity to curve these lines so that they form a smooth decision boundary?

2. How does the choice of the activation function influence the 3D graph? As in, if I had a **softmax** as the activation function at the output layer, how would I be able to model the problem and the decision boundary?

Comment: 1. The job of the **tanh** is to tell you on which side of the line the point lies. The further it is from the line, the closer the output to $\pm 1$. It limits the range of the signed distance from the line to (-1, 1) and, at the same time, non-linearly transforms the distance, so that in the 3D feature space the points do not lie in a plane any more. 2. I don't see a reason for using **softmax**, not in the hidden layer and, for just two classes, not in the output layer. But, theoretically speaking, you could have a square activation function and a cutoff at 0.5 and one neuron would suffice.